# Tooltip not working properly in `angular-ui-grid`

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-grid

I am using `angular-ui-grid` `v3.0.0-rc.22-e8fe073` and `bootstrap` tooltip inside a grid with `ui.bootstrap`.

Please find below tooltip template as below:

```
var templateWithTooltip = '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents"><a tooltip=\'{{COL_FIELD CUSTOM_FILTERS}}\' tooltip-append-to-body="true" tooltip-placement="right" style="text-decoration:none;top:0!important; white-space:pre;max-width:none;">{{ COL_FIELD CUSTOM_FILTERS }}</a></div>';
```

And using this in grid as `cellTemplate: templateWithTooltip`. And in css:

```
.tooltip-inner{
        word-wrap: break-word;
    }
```

The tooltip works fine for all the columns except last column. Please find below screenshot taken in resolution 1680x1050 :

[image]

I tried with `tooltip-placement="auto right" but this makes position even worst for other columns as well.

Tried with this as well:

```
cellClass: 'cellToolTip'
```

and

```
.cellToolTip {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

**Update:**

**Is it possible to call a function to assign the name of position to `tooltip-placement` attribute ? Like this:**

```
    $scope.fnGetTooltipPosition = function (context, source) {        
            var position = $(source).position();
            /*if (position.left > 1600) {
                return "left";
            }
            if (position.left < 1200) {
                return "left";
            }
            if (position.top < 1050){
                return "left";
            }*/
            return "left";
        }

var templateWithTooltip = '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents"><a tooltip=\'{{COL_FIELD CUSTOM_FILTERS}}\' tooltip-append-to-body="true" tooltip-placement={{fnGetTooltipPosition()}} style="text-decoration:none;white-space:pre;max-width:none;">{{ COL_FIELD CUSTOM_FILTERS }}</a></div>';
```

**I tried with above but the tooltip always come at top. If this can be done then I think we can get correct position for tooltip based on the resolution.**

**Update 2**

**Is it possible to call a function for each cell to get it's position and apply tooltip position respectively ? How do I call a function for each cell in a grid ?**

**Is it possible to display tooltip at bottom or left position for last column if the tooltip content does not fit with the screen resolution ?
How do I display tooltip properly for the last column of a grid ?**

Comment: Provide a pluncker link from next time onwards replicating your issue. It improves your chances of getting the solution quickly and correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to call a function and decide where to place the tooltip.

CellTemplate :

```
'<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents"><a tooltip=\'{{COL_FIELD CUSTOM_FILTERS}}\' tooltip-append-to-body="true" tooltip-placement={{grid.appScope.fnGetTooltipPosition(row)}} style="text-decoration:none;white-space:pre;max-width:none;">{{ COL_FIELD CUSTOM_FILTERS }}</a></div>'
```

Then define a function in the controller to get the position.

Function:

```
 $scope.fnGetTooltipPosition= function(row) {
     var index = $scope.gridOptions.data.indexOf(row.entity);
     //Check here whether index is equal to the (arrayLength-1), and return position
 };
```